# Why are emitted signals not received in multithreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, qt5

I have a problem, that remaining sent signals are not received after calling quit on `QThread` object.
The scenario contains 2 additional threads (`QThread` and `std::thread`) and the main execution thread. Let's call the `QThread` `Q`, the `std::thread` `T` and the main thread `M`.
In `M` I create `Q`, the Receiver-object `R` "living" in `Q` and the Sender-object `S`. Also a `std::thread` `T` is created executing a bunch if emits with `S`.

```
class Sender : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  std::vector<int> m_Sent;

  Sender()
  {
  }

public slots:
signals:
  void signal(int i);

public:
  void send(int i)
  {
    m_Sent.emplace_back(i);
    emit signal(i);
  }
};


class Receiver : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT;
public:
  std::vector<int> m_Received;

  Receiver()
  {
  }

  void Connect(Sender* s)
  {
    connect(s, &Sender::signal, this, &Receiver::slot, Qt::QueuedConnection);
  }

  void Disconnect(Sender* s)
  {
    disconnect(s, &Sender::signal, this, &Receiver::slot);
  }

public slots:
  void slot(int i)
  {
    m_Received.emplace_back(i);
  }

};

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  qint64 random_seed = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
  std::cout << "Setting random seed " << random_seed << "\n";
  std::srand(random_seed);
  std::unique_ptr<Receiver> R(new Receiver);
  std::unique_ptr<Sender> S(new Sender);
  auto actions = [&S]() {
    int i = 0;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point current =
            std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point finish =
            current + std::chrono::milliseconds(100);
    while (current < finish)
    {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(std::rand()%1000));
      S->send(i++);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(std::rand()%1000));
      S->send(i++);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(std::rand()%1000));
      S->send(i++);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(std::rand()%1000));
      S->send(i++);
      std::this_thread::sleep_until(current + std::chrono::milliseconds(17));
      current = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
  };

  std::unique_ptr<QThread> Q(new QThread());
  R->moveToThread(Q.get());
  R->Connect(S.get());
  Q->start();
  std::thread T(actions);
  T.join();

  // approach 1:
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(Q.get(), "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
  Q->wait(); // never returns
  // approach 2:
  Q->quit();
  Q->wait(); // missing events

  std::cout << "Sent:     ";
  for(auto v : S->m_Sent)
  {
    std::cout << v << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Received: ";
  for(auto v : R->m_Received)
  {
    std::cout << v << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I'm working on Windows with VS2013 and Qt 5.5.1. I tested it with kind of counter in `R` to track received signals. While debugging I went through all emits so all should be inserted to event loop in `Q`. After `Q.wait()` the counter for the slots do not correspond to the emitted signals. I would have expected the event loop with remaining input events was handled by `Q.quit()` or `Q.wait()` but seems not so, It's always that there is a cut of "event-stream" from a certain point onward. I tried now for 4 days going through Qt-Docu and several other stuff found by google, but no proposal worked so far.

Comment: Please provide real code instead of pseudocode. A `main.cpp` that would demonstrate this issue might be shorter than your pseudocode, and won't need any comments.

Comment: not sure if the example will really help, because its a threading issue.

Comment: Why wouldn't it help? Either you have a real issue and then there's code that reproduces it, or you don't. There's no middle ground.

Comment: the current example reproduces the problem, but it's more of a never return from wait instead of missing events. the missing events come if I just call `Q.get()->quit()` instead of invoking and waiting.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure since the documentation is not crystal clear, but what makes you think that the even loop is processing all pending events before exiting ? My assumption would be that there is a check "should I exit" at every loop and that it can discard some pending events when the exit flag is set.

In order to summarize the discussion below, I would suggest to add a new signal that you emit from wherever you want (say for instance from the std::thread once you have emitted everything you wanted) that would get into the QThread event loop queue and be connected to the QThread quit method so that the thread exits when being processed.
You can also avoid defining a new signal if you want.

Your code would look like (not tested):

```
Sender S = new Sender();
QThread Q = new QThread();
Receiver R = new Receiver();
R->moveToThread(Q);
connect(S, &Sender::signal, R, &Receiver::slot, Qt::QueuedConnection);

Q->start();
while(!Q.isRunning())
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}

std::thread T([&S](){
    emit S->signal(); // only an example, several other connects are used too
})

T.join();

QMetaObject::invokeMethod(Q, "quit",
                          Qt::QueuedConnection);

Q.wait();
```

Comment: You are right, that is just an assumption I made, I think I read a note somewhere but not sure anymore ;-). Then the question would be how can I guarantee to handle all remaining events and then quit the `QThread Q`. I found a function in the docu `hasPendingEvents` but it was not encouraged to be used, so I don't.

Comment: Maybe you should have a special signal you emit from the std thread and catch in your QThread that would make the thread exit ? Since it would only be caught once all previous events are processed, it would work as expected ? Actually you probably have to wonder "when exactly should my QThread stop" since you may have a race condition between your main thread and your std::thread.
For instance:
    connect(S, &Sender::poisonPill, Q, &QThread::quit, Qt::QueuedConnection);

Comment: There are only connects of user defined signals and slots no special connects to Qt-slots (like quit, deleteLater,...). My user defined slots just make local operations on `R` and not emitting further signals or calling Qt methods.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer, sorry. I was suggesting a change to make in your code (add a new signal that will stop the QThread) in order to have the behavior you want.

Comment: Actually the `lastSignal` don't need to be in `Sender S`, if I emit it after `T.join()` it should be fine as well. This is relevant if I can't change `S` or `R` and only know when last signal was sent. then I need some dummy object connecting to slot `QThread::quit`  of `Q`. Is there a way to put the `quit` action right at end of event loop of the `Q` without a specific sender?

Comment: Yep, as I said, you can put it wherever you want ! I will edit the answer to answer your point.

Comment: Ok the invokeMethod adds the `quit()` method after the last emitted signal to the event loop, but now it seems the program stucks at the `Q.wait()` statement. If I pause in the Debug mode the event loop seems to wait for more events. It is at statement `waitRet = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(nCount, pHandles, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT, MWMO_ALERTABLE | MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);` in the EventDispatcher. I tried to use the `wakeUp()` before `wait()` of the EventDispatcher, but does not help so far.

Comment: I am a bit surprised, you may have another thread doing something wrong ? I guess you need to write a small reproducer (and not peuso code as you did) so that I can try on my side.

Comment: Your example prints the following when running it "QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132977/discussion-between-feuerteufel-and-canardmoussant).